# Email with multiple attachments triggered by a button

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net

I want to create a button that would trigger to send an email with all the documents in a certain document library.

I tried creating this on workflows but unfortunately I can't seem to add multiple attachments and only Encoded Absolute URL works.

Is there a workaround for this using SPD, if not how do I do this using visual studio?
My problem is that the contents of the emails are accessed in a list that has the To, CC, Subject and body.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find an OOTB solution to this.  However you may look at installing a 3rd party component to add a more sophisticated email action to your workflows.

Comment: Thanks for replying, a third party was not an option due to budget contraints. Can't this be done using visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

There is a codeplex solution for this- http://sendemailsp2010.codeplex.com/

When the feature is active, there will be added a button “Send documents as e-mail” to the section “Share & Track” in the ribbon of all document libraries. This button will be active only if at least one document is selected. After clicking on “Send documents as email” the dialog “New Mail-Dialog” of Outlook will be opened and the selected documents will be automatically added as attachments.There is an additional possibility to send a single document as an e-mail via context menu too.

Now, the customization you require would be to fetch details from a List where your To,CC, Subject and body resides and somehow attach it to the dialopg of Outlook.

Good Luck.